# Добавление поддержки CJK (Китайский, Корейский, Японский) языков используя PdfSharp 1.50

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

Как добавить поддержку языков **CJK** (китайский, японский, корейский) в проект с помощью **PdfSharp 1.50**?

Я нахожу на форумах решение для редактирования исходных файлов библиотеки PdfSharp. Но такое решение мне не подходит.

Итак, как я могу сделать это без редактирования исходных файлов библиотеки PdfSharp? Сейчас символы этих языков не распознаются в Pdf-документе.

Comment: Вам очевидно не подходит эта библиотека. Если что MS Word умеет читать PDF, загрузите документ в Word, и пробуйте через Interop достать то что вам нужно. Либо ищите другое решение.

Comment: Капитан Очевидность подсказывает: обратиться к разработчику PdfSharp, а не на stackoverflow.